# "Pretty" date generator

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this "pretty" date string generator in C# - pass it a date and it returns a string with "5 minutes ago" or "2 weeks, 3 days ago", etc.

It's a little verbose and hogs 61 lines, and I'm wondering if I'm missing out on some nice C# features or something. What (if any) is the best way to clean up this code? Are there any cool c# features I can use here?

```
public static string getTimeSpan(DateTime postDate)
{
    string stringy = "";
    TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(postDate);
    double years = Math.Floor(diff.TotalDays / 365);
    double weeks = Math.Floor(diff.TotalDays / 7);
    double days = diff.Days;
    double hours = diff.Hours + days * 24;
    double minutes = diff.Minutes + hours * 60;
    if (minutes <= 1) {
        stringy = "Just Now";
    } else if (years >= 1) {
        if (years >= 2) {
            stringy = years.ToString() + " years ago";
        } else {
            stringy = "1 year ago";
        }
    } else if (weeks >= 1) {
        if ((days - weeks * 7) > 0) {
            if ((days - weeks * 7) > 1) {
                stringy = ", " + (days - weeks * 7).ToString() + " days";
            } else {
                stringy = ", " + (days - weeks * 7).ToString() + " day";
            }
        }
        if (weeks >= 2) {
            stringy = weeks.ToString() + " weeks" + stringy + " ago";
        } else {
            stringy = "1 week" + stringy + " ago";
        }
    } else if (days >= 1) {
        if ((hours - days * 24) > 0) {
            if ((hours - days * 24) > 1) {
                stringy = ", " + (hours - days * 24).ToString() + " hours";
            } else {
                stringy = ", " + (hours - days * 24).ToString() + " hour";
            }
        }
        if (days >= 2) {
            stringy = days.ToString() + " days" + stringy + " ago";
        } else {
            stringy = "1 day" + stringy + " ago";
        }
    } else if (hours >= 1) {
        if ((minutes - hours * 60) > 0) {
            if ((minutes - hours * 60) > 1) {
                stringy = ", " + (minutes - hours * 60).ToString() + " minutes";
            } else {
                stringy = ", " + (minutes - hours * 60).ToString() + " minute";
            }
        }
        if (hours >= 2) {
            stringy = hours.ToString() + " hours" + stringy + " ago";
        } else {
            stringy = "1 hour" + stringy + " ago";
        }
    } else if (minutes > 1) {
        stringy = minutes.ToString() + " minutes ago";
    }
    return stringy;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Use PascalCase for the method name
2. Move the calc for years and months lower to be minutely "more efficient"
3. Use inline `return` to reduces nesting
4. Use ternary operator (`?:`) for simple logic to reduce `if/else` clutter
5. Use the `format` override of `ToString(string format)` to reduce string concats
6. Use `string.Format` with a ternary to reduce duplication

The shorter version I came up with is 40 lines, but you can judge if it readable enough.

```
    public static string GetTimeSpan(DateTime postDate) {
        string stringy = string.Empty;
        TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(postDate);
        double days = diff.Days;
        double hours = diff.Hours + days*24;
        double minutes = diff.Minutes + hours*60;
        if (minutes <= 1) {
            return "Just Now";
        }
        double years = Math.Floor(diff.TotalDays/365);
        if (years >= 1) {
            return string.Format("{0} year{1} ago", years, years >= 2 ? "s" : null);
        }
        double weeks = Math.Floor(diff.TotalDays/7);
        if (weeks >= 1) {
            double partOfWeek = days - weeks*7;
            if (partOfWeek > 0) {
                stringy = string.Format(", {0} day{1}", partOfWeek, partOfWeek > 1 ? "s" : null);
            }
            return string.Format("{0} week{1}{2} ago", weeks, weeks >= 2 ? "s" : null, stringy);
        }
        if (days >= 1) {
            double partOfDay = hours - days*24;
            if (partOfDay > 0) {
                stringy = string.Format(", {0} hour{1}", partOfDay, partOfDay > 1 ? "s" : null);
            }
            return string.Format("{0} day{1}{2} ago", days, days >= 2 ? "s" : null, stringy);
        }
        if (hours >= 1) {
            double partOfHour = minutes - hours*60;
            if (partOfHour > 0) {
                stringy = string.Format(", {0} minute{1}", partOfHour, partOfHour > 1 ? "s" : null);
            }
            return string.Format("{0} hour{1}{2} ago", hours, hours >= 2 ? "s" : null, stringy);
        }

        // Only condition left is minutes > 1
        return minutes.ToString("# minutes ago");
    }
```

Comment: wow thanks! I didn't even know about half these operators and methods and such!

Comment: It is important to remove last `return` in such cases so compiler will verify that all cases are checked and handled and there is no scenario when this method will return initial value which is `string.Empty`

Comment: Updated the last line to be more explicit with the final return.

Comment: How about future dates? :p

Comment: The last line should be `return string.Format("{0} minutes ago", minutes);` as `minutes.ToString("{0} minutes ago")` will return `{xxx} minutes ago`.

Comment: @monoblaine You are right, the code was incorrect. I have edited it to use `#` instead of `{0}`. See it in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gxNsxU

Comment: Can reduce a bit of boilerplate using string interpolation instead of `string.Format`

Answer (score 6):

Some things are repeated:

```
days - weeks * 7
hours - days * 24
minutes - hours * 60
```

These can and should be made into their own variables - but what you are really after seems to be

```
days % 7
hours % 24
minutes % 60
```

You can replace:

```
double hours = diff.Hours + days * 24;
```

with

```
double hours = diff.TotalHours;
```

There is also a TotalMinutes. You can just use the Math.Floor() of these values to get an int.

I see that you are going for a single exit point for this function, but I think that readability would be improved if you got some of the simpler paths shorter:

```
if (minutes <= 1)         
  return "Just Now"; 

if (years >= 1) {        
  if (years >= 2) {
    return years.ToString() + " years ago";        
  } else {
    return "1 year ago";
  }
```

EDIT to add:

There's a repeated block of code that could be refactored to its own function:

```
if ((days - weeks * 7) > 0) {
   if ((days - weeks * 7) > 1) {
      stringy = ", " + (days - weeks * 7).ToString() + " days";            
   } else {
      stringy = ", " + (days - weeks * 7).ToString() + " day";
   }
}
if (weeks >= 2) {
   stringy = weeks.ToString() + " weeks" + stringy + " ago";
} else {
   stringy = "1 week" + stringy + " ago";
}
```

The body of the extracted function would look like:

```
if (smallUnitCount > 0) {
   if (smallUnitCount > 1) {
      stringy = String.Format(", {0} {1}", smallUnitCount.ToString() , smallUnitPluralName);            
   } else {
      stringy = String.Format(", {0} {1}", smallUnitCount.ToString() , smallUnitSingularName);
   }
}
if (largeUnitCount >= 2) {
   stringy = String.Format("{0} {1}{2} ago", largeUnitCount.ToString, largeUnitPluralName, stringy);
} else {
   stringy = String.Format("{0} {1}{2} ago", largeUnitCount.ToString, largeUnitSingularName, stringy);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use casting `double` to `int` instead of `Floor` in your case. Firstly because I'm a little bit cautious about equality comparison of doubles in `years >= 1`. I would write it in this way:

```
int years = (int)(diff.TotalDays/365);
```

Comment: would doing so accomplish the same as Floor? that is, would casting .8 to an int return 0? Because that's important (i don't want .8 to round to 1 and have the function say that it's been a year when it's only really been 80% of a year)

Comment: Yep, with positive doubles casting to `int` does `Floor` exactly. See **Explicit conversion** section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx). It has exactly your sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it an extension, so you can do

```
string result = DateTime.Now.GetTimeSpan();
```

Here is how I did it a few time ago

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Provide extentions for the DateTime Object.
    /// </summary>
    public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the relative time for a datetime.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dateTime">The datetime to get the relative time.</param>
        /// <returns>A relative time in english.</returns>
        public static string GetTimeSpan(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dateTime);

            if (diff.TotalMinutes < 1)
            {
                return string.Format("{0:D2} second{1} ago", diff.Seconds, PluralizeIfNeeded(diff.Seconds));
            }

            if (diff.TotalHours < 1)
            {
                return string.Format("{0:D2} minute{1} ago", diff.Minutes, PluralizeIfNeeded(diff.Minutes));
            }

            if (diff.TotalDays < 1)
            {
                return string.Format("{0:D2} hour{2} and {1:D2} minute{3} ago", diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, PluralizeIfNeeded(diff.Hours), PluralizeIfNeeded(diff.Minutes));
            }

            if (diff.TotalDays <= 2)
            {
                return string.Format(
                    "{0:D2} day{3}, {1:D2} hour{4} and {2:D2} minute{5} ago",
                    diff.Days,
                    diff.Hours,
                    diff.Minutes,
                    PluralizeIfNeeded(diff.Days),
                    PluralizeIfNeeded(diff.Hours),
                    PluralizeIfNeeded(diff.Minutes));
            }

            if (diff.TotalDays <= 30)
            {
                return string.Format("{0:D2} days ago", diff.TotalDays);
            }

            return string.Format("{0:g}", dateTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a 's' if value is > 1.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="testValue">The value to test.</param>
        /// <returns>An 's' if value is > 1, otherwise an empty string.</returns>
        private static string PluralizeIfNeeded(int testValue)
        {
            return testValue > 1 ? "s" : string.Empty;
        }
    }
```